# "Error in 'mutate()':" in purposeful selection step 1 code using R

Tags: r, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I am a Medicine student and fairly new to R. For my research I am trying to find predictors for intraoperative blood loss, and I am trying to use the 'purposeful' package from Github to apply the purposeful selection method.

I have inputed the following code:

```
    purposeful::purposeful_step_1(
      data = imputed,
      outcome = "ebl",
      predictors = c("age", "gender", "bmi", "charlson", "add_comorb", "path_fracture", "pain",     "ecog", "asia_pre_cat", "prim_tumor", "tumor_region", "more2_spine_met", "other_bone_mets", "spine_mets", "visc_mets", "brain_mets", "local_radiation", "previous_systemic", "ellipsoid_cm3", "bilsky", "hgb", "wbc", "plt", "lymph", "neut", "creatinine", "calcium", "albumin", "time_prim_surg", "operation", "levels_operated"),
      ref_level = NULL,
      cutoff_value = 0.25,
      conf_level = 0.95,
      format = TRUE,
      exponentiate = FALSE)
```

In which "ebl" is my outcome variable, a continuous variable of blood loss in mL. All predictors are clinical values which are either dichotomous, ordinal or continuous.

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
    Error in `mutate()`:
    ℹ In argument: `res_univ = purrr::map(...)`.
    Caused by error in `purrr::map()`:
    ℹ In index: 1.
    Caused by error:
    ! y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
    Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or how I could fix this? I have tried the code with another (categorical) variable as outcome and that works, is it not possible to perform this code on continuous variables? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at help page for `purposeful_step_1` it says *"Univariable logistic regression for variables of interest"*. Logistic regression is for binary responses, usually either coded as 1s and 0s or a number of trials with a proportion of successes.

Logistic regression is not for continuous variables. So I think the answer is **no**, it is not possible to perform this code on continuous variables.

Comment: Thank you so much!

I understood that I will need to use linear regression for my continuous outcome, and found various methods for this online such as the stepwise regression. Since I have multiple predictive variables, do you have any advice what kind of regression I could use in R?

Comment: I can't think of any linear regression methods that are limited to a single predictive variable. `lm()` is the base function for fitting linear models. Stepwise regression should generally be avoided - if you need an algorithm for variable selection I much prefer the Lasso.